# R extract parts of a string based on punctuation characters that appear more than once

Tags: r, string, split

I have spent a lot of time reading successful answers on how to extract part of a string using substr and substring. Still, I am having trouble applying answers because I cannot differentiate where specific punctuation characters are used to indicate when to start and stop selecting other punctuation characters, if those characters appear more than once within the string.

In a generalised case, I would like to split my string in several places based on re-ocurring characters of "_" and "."

In my individual case, a cell in one column of my dataframe contains a filename as a string, and I would like to use that string to generate strings in 3 subsequent columns on the same row.

To demonstrate, the string might look like: "Name_12. Word_CsvData.txt" and that should be split without referring to numeric character positions into "Name", "12", "Word"

To do this, I am aiming to find out how to extract part of a string:

1) from the beginning of the string to the first instance of an underscore character.

2) from the first underscore to the first full stop.

3) from the space to the second underscore character.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `library(stringr)`, `str_match(s, "^([^_]+)_([^.]+)\\.\\s*([^_]+)")`

Comment: Maybe `strsplit("Name_12. Word_CsvData.txt", split="[._]")` to split and then keep the first 3 elements? Here, `strsplit("Name_12. Word_CsvData.txt", split="[._]")[[1]][1:3]` would work, but for a longer set of strings, you'd probably use `lapply`.